# Import выбранных таблиц Oracle

Tags: oracle

Подскажите пожалуйста как импортировать нужные мне таблицы из бэкапа ? 
Делаю следующим путем

```
#imp MILLER/KOLOBOK FILE=file.DAT LOG=logf.log feedback=1000 tables=(t1,t2,t3,t4) FULL = Y;
```

получаю ошибку синтаксиса '(' 
если убрать круглые скобки импорт не начинается, если убрать full, так же ничего не происходит. Подскажите что я не правильно делаю ?

Comment: @lDrakonl запарился уже, извиняюсь, поправил

Comment: когда вы указываете параметр `FULL=Y`, это импорт всей БД. Скорее всего не возможно указать список таблиц и приэтом написать `FULL=Y`. Еще попробуйте убрать пробелы внутри `FULL = Y`

Comment: а еще решеточка вначале случайно не обозначает комментирование всей строки?

Answer (score 2):

У Вас перечислен список таблиц и при этом указан параметр `FULL = Y`. Так нельзя. Либо всю бд, либо отдельные таблицы.
При этом список таблиц не привязан к схемам. Имя таблицы может повторяться внутри схемы.

В зависимости от требуемой задачи:

1) Импортнуть всю БД. Уберите перечисление таблиц. `FULL=Y` подразумевает импорт всей БД целиком.

2) Импортнуть нужные таблицы. Используйте параметры `FROMUSER`, `TOUSER`, `TABLES` и при этом `FULL=N`.
`FROMUSER`  и `TOUSER` не обязаны быть одинаковыми.

Рекомендую избегать лишних пробелов внутри параметров. У меня под Виндовс это приводило к странностям считывания параметров

Comment: Давайте по порядку : - пробелов нет, здесь сделал для лучшей читабельности. Я уже понял что Full=y это импорт всей базы но в другой теме я столкнулся с проблемой которую не знаю как обойти из-за этой проблемы слетели sys и system. Если я убираю FULL то происходит импортирование кодировок 2 шт. и процесс завершается. За день я все варианты перепробовал кроме выбора пользователей. И ОС у меня CentOS7. А еще не может быть проблем с тем что exp снимался с 10g Win serv 2003 а imp на 11g2 CentOS7 ??

Comment: #значит начало командной строки

Comment: Версии роли не играют. В этом и суть. Экспорт снимался с помощью `exp` или `expdp` ?

Comment: `exp` с этим я уже тоже столкнулся, одно с другим не дружит ))

Comment: уже попробовали указать схемы для импорта явно(при перечислении таблиц)? Без указания схемы Оракл не сможет однозначно установить нужные таблицы

Comment: нет не пробовал, может в этом и вся беда ? Просто я в теме указания схем немного запутался (учусь еще). Как понять какие схемы нужны ? в лог файле экспорта они есть ? как их создать ? и как их указать ?

Comment: Схема в терминах оракла - это пользователь. При обращении к таблицам у таблиц получается адрес `<имя пользователя(схема)>.<имя таблицы>`. Если нужны таблицы только 1го пользователя, то используйте параметры `fromuser` и `touser` и перечислите нужные таблицы. Вообще, если бы вы привели ваш пример с названиямми ваших таблиц, а не с учебника, было бы проще

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62165/discussion-between-ethernets-and-ldrakonl).

Comment: перенес тему в чат, если вам удобно посмотрите пожалуйста